# Returning an object "instance" asynchronously through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

Besides jQuery's AJAX functions I'm very limited in my understanding of *"asynchronous"* JavaScript.

I've created a system where I'm loading external Javascript files in as 'modules' in order to keep things tidy and lightweight. The main inspiration + implementation for doing this can be found [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/).

So, for example, a JS file called `foo.js` might contain the following JS object with set attributes:

```
var bar = { 
   a:1,
   b:2
}
```

After this external file has been loaded it's accessible via `window.bar` thereafter. So typing in `window.bar.a` (alternatively `bar.a`) into the browser's Developer Tool JS console should return:

```
1
```

My issue arises when I try to assign the `bar` object to a variable, this will often be resolved synchronously before the external JS module has been loaded and usually contain `undefined` - boo!

This is my attempt so far: basically return the object instance if it already exists in the `window`, otherwise wait for it to be loaded and then return it (*ideally*):

```
var val = getInstance('bar');
```

Which calls my function:

```
function getInstance(name) {
    if(typeof window[name] === 'object'){
        return window[name];
    } else { 
        $(window).on('load', window[name], function() { 
            return window[name];
        });
    }
}
```

Which, of course returns `undefined` when I `console.log(val)`.

I know for a fact here that I'm expecting the object `bar` to come through asynchronously to `val`. To which I can then go ahead and start referencing the `bar` instance through `val` (i.e. `val.a == 1`).

I've made an effort to skim over jQuery's Deferred Object (`$.Deferred`) - to which my understanding disappears, but I'm on a tight deadline and would like to know now rather than a few days down the line if I'm on the right track in getting and instance of `bar` into `val`.

Any help, pointers or comments are much appreciated!

Comment: *"otherwise wait for it to be loaded and then return it (ideally):"* can't work asynchronously. I'd suggest using either an existing framework that solves this problem (such as requirejs) or building something similar.

Comment: use a callback function

Comment: @KevinB Hence my question about the whole matter. Getting an instance without having to rely on callbacks is my main objective here - it's simply placeholder code to *try* and replicate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't, there must be a callback. Even a setInterval that continuously checks for it to become available requires a callback.

Comment: zesda, you appear to be describing "jsonp", without using the term "jsonp". Google it and do some reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Kevin B has given you the correct answer.

Considering your timeline and unfamiliarity with the topic, I would suggest concatenating and minifying your JavaScript files instead of doing async modules.

Otherwise you will need to invest the time in understanding how to use a module loader like require or yepnope.  The article you reference doesn't address loading multiple modules simultaneously, which may be a requirement for you.  Any path you take to async script loading is going to require you to leverage callbacks to organize the order that your code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxRequests = [];
var scriptUrlCollection = ['script1.js', 'script2.js', 'script3.js'];
$(scriptUrlCollection).each(function( index, url ) {
    ajaxRequests.push($.getScript(url));
});
$.when.apply($, ajaxRequests).done(function() { / *execute your code */);
```

You may use ajax to load your scripts, then execute your code when all of them complete, thanks to deferred objects.

Each ajax request returns a jQuery deferred object, which we add to the `ajaxRequests` array. When all of these deferred objects are resolved, the `done()` method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know now rather than a few days down the line if I'm on the right track

Yes. [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) (like jQuery's Deferred implementation) are the way to go.

> in getting and instance of bar into val

Not exactly. Promises in JS are not transparent, they're more like proxy objects. You still need a callback:

```
getInstance("bar").then(function(val) {
    // this function is executed asynchronously
    // and the `bar` instance is available here
});
```